# vimtex: Avoid aligning in align environment in the document

Tags: plugin-vimtex

So I'm using vimtex, and it's great, but there is one thing that is so annoying and I cannot believe that people actually use that feature.
Namely, say I write something like

```
\begin{align}
  x &= blabla
\end{align}
```

If I insert a latex-newline `\\`, then a newline and an alignment character `&`, vim does the following "for me", which really is totally contrary to all my hopes and dreams:

```
\begin{align}
  x &= blabla \\
    &
\end{align}
```

What I want is the far superior

```
\begin{align}
  x &= blabla \\
  &
\end{align}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

There is an [oldish thread on github](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/613), but the solutions given there don't seem to work anymore.

Surely I can't be the only experiencing this :(

Comment: Hi and welcome! In the thread you linked, the `g:vimtex_indent_align_on_ampersand` option is mentioned. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Biggybi: Hi and thanks :) Yes, vim tells me that that variable does not exist :(

Comment: You just need to `:let g:the_var = 0` before the plugin loads, probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I'm using vimtex, and it's great

Glad you like it! :)

> but there is one thing that is so annoying ... What I want is the far superior

This is clearly opinionated! If it was objectively "far superior", then I would of course make it the default. But I personally prefer to align on the `&`s. I don't consider my preference superior and I don't find it surprising that people disagree with it. Which is why I made this optional. To disable, you can add the following line to your `.vimrc` (Vim) or `init.vim` (neovim):

```
let g:vimtex_indent_on_ampersands = 0
```

For more info and context, please see `:help vimtex-indent` and `:help g:vimtex_indent_on_ampersands`.

Comment: Haha, I was of course only being half-serious/facetious. I wrote that while fairly frustraded with the issue. Thanks for your awesome plugin! It makes my texing so much faster, now I can spend my paper-writing time with fussing over not being able to compute things lmao.
But in any case, it works now, I didn't know that you had to put it in the `.vimrc`, I assumed you could change the value during runtime.

Comment: No problem, and again I'm glad you did VimTeX useful! Feel free to open issues on GitHub if you have any problems :)